# Apache Syncope integration with Spring security

Tags: spring-security, integration, apache-syncope

Want to know how to integrate Apache Syncope with Spring Security with a modular architecture and a bit of coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this topic has been yet discussed into syncope user ML.
Please, take a look at [1] for more details.

Kind regards.

[1] http://syncope-user.1051894.n5.nabble.com/Apache-Syncope-internal-resource-for-storing-credentials-to-provide-authentication-to-a-simple-Sprinn-td5708091.html

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty late to this thread, but I too was searching for some real world problems, if any, faced by developers who have tried to used syncope. 
As for a ready reference example, I did find this [blog](https://www.tirasa.net/en/blog/syncope-via-spring-boot) and [github repo](https://github.com/Tirasa/syncopeSpringBoot)